# React - refactoring code with IF and Else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

I'm studying react and I've worked out some logic for rendering a DIV, but I know it's redundant and I don't know exactly how to refactor it. This is the code:

```
renderHeader() {
const {
  course_module_index
} = this.state;
if(course_module_index === 0)
return (
  <>
    <h4 className="col-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 color__primary1 bold">Conversation</h4>
    <p className="col-8 offset-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 body2 back__type">
      Practice your English in the conversation classes available in the schedule below. you can enter a
      class up to 10 min. after your start time, but we recommend that you book a time as
      class size is limited.
    </p>
    <div className="header__opening-class">
      <h6> Opening Classes Available!</h6>
      <p> Mon/Wed/Fri from 9:00h to 9:30h | Tues/Thurs from 7:00 pm to 7:30 pm </p>
    </div>
    <hr ref={this.conversationBlockRef} className="margin-zero col-12 md-col-8 sm-col-4" />
  </>
);
return (
  <>
    <h4 className="col-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 color__primary1 bold">Conversation</h4>
    <p className="col-8 offset-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 body2 back__type">
      Practice your English in the conversation classes available in the schedule below. you can enter a
      class up to 10 min. after your start time, but we recommend that you book a time as
      class size is limited.
    </p>
    <hr ref={this.conversationBlockRef} className="margin-zero col-12 md-col-8 sm-col-4" />
  </>
);
```

}

Comment: If the only difference is that `header__opening-class` div seems like [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) would be sufficient, although it's difficult to see if that's the only change.

Comment: I think this question is better off being posted n https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, that being said, you can always use ternary operator for such scenario, e.g.: `return your_condition ? <></> : <></>`

Comment: Please describe clearly which section are you trying to display with condition and which section are you trying to display by default ? Its not very clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React elements can be stored in a variable so they can be used later, and you can use a condition to decide whether to render an element

```
  renderHeader() {
    const { course_module_index } = this.state;

    // use a condition to conditionally render this element
    const schedule = course_module_index === 0 && (
      <div className="header__opening-class">
        <h6>Opening Classes Available!</h6>
        <p>
          Mon/Wed/Fri from 9:00h to 9:30h | Tues/Thurs from 7:00 pm to 7:30 pm
        </p>
      </div>
    );

    // Use the schedule variable within the following expression.
    // If `schedule` is false, then React will render nothing in its place
    return (
      <>
        <h4 className="col-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 color__primary1 bold">
          Conversation
        </h4>
        <p className="col-8 offset-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 body2 back__type">
          Practice your English in the conversation classes available in the
          schedule below. you can enter a class up to 10 min. after your start
          time, but we recommend that you book a time as class size is limited.
        </p>
        {schedule}
        <hr
          ref={this.conversationBlockRef}
          className="margin-zero col-12 md-col-8 sm-col-4"
        />
      </>
    );
  }
```

If you find it easier to read, you can use the condition directly inside the JSX:

```
  renderHeader() {
    const { course_module_index } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <h4 className="col-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 color__primary1 bold">
          Conversation
        </h4>
        <p className="col-8 offset-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 body2 back__type">
          Practice your English in the conversation classes available in the
          schedule below. you can enter a class up to 10 min. after your start
          time, but we recommend that you book a time as class size is limited.
        </p>
        {course_module_index === 0 && (
          /* This won't render if the condition was false */
          <div className="header__opening-class">
            <h6>Opening Classes Available!</h6>
            <p>
              Mon/Wed/Fri from 9:00h to 9:30h | Tues/Thurs from 7:00 pm to 7:30
              pm
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
        <hr
          ref={this.conversationBlockRef}
          className="margin-zero col-12 md-col-8 sm-col-4"
        />
      </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used react functional component structure. You should not have to repeat two return statements. Just call functions as you need and put your view inside it. You can have multiple functions as well if your content becomes big and contains too many conditions, just separate them out in different component.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/old-haze-t3w1w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [moduleIndex, setModuleIndex] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setModuleIndex(1);
  });
  const _renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {moduleIndex ? (
          <div className="header__opening-class">
            <h6> Opening Classes Available!</h6>
            <p>
              {" "}
              Mon/Wed/Fri from 9:00h to 9:30h | Tues/Thurs from 7:00 pm to 7:30
              pm{" "}
            </p>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <h4 className="col-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 color__primary1 bold">
          Conversation
        </h4>
        <p className="col-8 offset-3 md-col-8 sm-col-4 body2 back__type">
          Practice your English in the conversation classes available in the
          schedule below. you can enter a class up to 10 min. after your start
          time, but we recommend that you book a time as class size is limited.
        </p>
        <hr
          ref={this.conversationBlockRef}
          className="margin-zero col-12 md-col-8 sm-col-4"
        />
      </>
    );
  };

  return <div className="App">{_renderHeader()}</div>;
}
```